# How do I test to make sure that methods were called in a chain in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I want to test whether or not something of the form

```
function testThis() {
  something.first().second();
}
```

was called but I also want to make sure that the test does not pass if the function was written as

```
function testThis1() {
  something.one();
  something.two();
}
```

I found this great blog post about testing chained methods being called that said to do something along the lines of

```
var something, first, second;

something = {};
first = {};

something.one = jasmine.createSpy('firstFn').and.returnValue(first);
first.second = jasmine.createSpy('secondFn')

expect(something.one).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(first.second).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

but this essentially tests `testThis1`. It still passes when the method calls are not chained.